# What is an elegant way to parse huge datasets and search through them without using core data?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Assuming there a JSON file with 100k+ records. What be an elegant approach to parse through this data and subsequently use this data to search through?

The approach that i have been leading with:
**For parsing:**  Parse through this entirely and keep the data in a local swift data-set.
**For searching:** divide the data set in a dictionary with some sort of hashed keys to quickly jump through the data while searching.

Eager to find more efficient ways to achieve this.

Comment: Be sure to check out https://github.com/michaeleisel/zippyjson

Comment: the elegant way is not to store "huge datasets" on client, and rather to create a web/cloud service that holds a "huge dataset" and sends only relevant subset to a client

Comment: This wouldn't be a question if it was this obvious. The usecase demands that the file be processed on the client